# What would you call this expression: “Oof!”

Tags: single-word-requests

When someone is impressed by something, or taken aback, they will sometimes make a noise that is usually typed out as, “Oof!” However, the “f” isn’t always vocalized. Sometimes it’s just a flow of air that follows an “oo” sound. So, the “oof” sound isn’t necessarily a word, but a sound in an of itself - like a sigh, a huff, or a scoff.

Imagine, if you will, someone seeing a beautiful car. They might say, “Oof! Look at that car!”

If you were to transcribe that sentence, what word would you use to describe the “oof” sound?

Comment: _Oof_ is the conventional spelling for that interjection. And since English spelling does not represent English pronunciation, it doesn't matter whether the final /f/ is present or not. Most spoken English is not really representable in writing the way it's spoken -- it's fulla contractions n variations n all kindza stuff. So don worry about it.

Comment: In New York, we considered it Italian street talk blending a grunt, Wow, and Oh No! Could be a mini minced F bomb.

Answer (score 2):

This is called an [exclamation.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/exclamation) (Collins Dictionary). An exclamation is a sound, word, or sentence that is spoken suddenly, loudly, or emphatically and that expresses excitement, admiration, shock, or anger. [Here](https://oxfordlanguageclub.com/page/blog/interjections-in-english-you-need-to-know) (Oxford Language Club) is a list of common exclamatory words.

Psst, [here](https://www.englishgrammar.org/list-interjections/) (English Grammar)  is another list. Yoo-hoo. Happy exclamation.

Comment: If you're looking for an Official Part Of Speech, it's the last and least one on the list, the _Interjection_. Remember, at the end, "Prepositions, Conjunctions, and Interjections"?

Comment: Please edit your answer so that it follows [our Help Center's guidance on how to reference work by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). We are not a link farm, and a bare unattributed link does no one any good. Our reuse licence allows for plain-text reuse, and so the link would be lost if not given in actual text.

Comment: Provided link, name of source and meaning if word/words is not in common use